# Limit of a oscillating function: when it does not exist?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, limits, functions

Is it possible to say the following?

> If $f$ and $g$ are real functions and
>
> 1. $\not \exists \,\,\, \mathrm{lim}_{x \to x_0} g(x) $
> 2. $\mathrm{lim}_{x \to x_0} f(x) \neq 0$
> 3. $|g(x)|>C \,\,\, \forall C \in \mathbb{R}$
>
> Then
>
> $$\not \exists \,\,\, \mathrm{lim}_{x \to x_0} f(x) g(x)$$

That is, the only way to have an existing limit of an oscillating not limited function is that it is multiplied by an infinitesimal function.

Does the same implication still hold if condition 3. is not present? That is $g(x)$ oscillates but it is limited, but $f(x)$ does not go to zero, then the limit doesn't exists?

Comment: You are using the $\exists$ symbol incorrectly. If you want to indicate that a limit does not exist, you must write "does not exist" or define your own notation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_quantification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the third condition.

First of all, note that there exists some interval $(x_0-\epsilon, x_0+\epsilon)$ on which $f(x)\neq 0$.

Now, assume that  $$\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)g(x)$$ exists.

Define $$F(x) = f(x)\cdot g(x)$$

Then, from the properties of limits, since $\lim_{x\to x_0} F(x)$ exists and $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)$ exists and is nonzero, the limit $$\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{F(x)}{f(x)}$$

also exists. Since $\frac{F(x)}{f(x)} = g(x)$, this means that $\lim_{x\to x_0}g(x)$ also exists, a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! If I may ask, considering now the existance of the limit: if $\not \exists \,\, \mathrm{lim}_{x \to x_0} g(x)$ but $\mathrm{lim}_{x \to x_0} f(x)=0$ can I say that $\mathrm{lim}_{x \to x_0} g(x)f(x)=0$ without adding the condition $|g(x)|< C \,\,\, , C>0$? Or is this last condition necessary?

Comment: @Gianolepo The condition is neccesary, since you can have $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}[x}$, in which case $\lim_{x\to x_0} g(x)f(x)=1\neq 0$, or even $g(x)=\frac{\sin(1/x)}{x}, in which case the limit of the product doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $\exists a:=\,\,\, \mathrm{lim}_{x \to x_0} f(x) g(x)$. Then we have that $f(x) \ne 0$ near $x_0$. Hence, with $b:= \lim_{x \to x_0}f(x)$,

$ g(x)= \frac{f(x)g(x)}{f(x)} \to a/b$ for $x \to x_0$, a contradiction.